# Freeing memory when using ctypes

Tags: python, c, numpy, ctypes

I am using ctypes to try and speed up my code.

My problem is similar to the one in this tutorial : https://cvstuff.wordpress.com/2014/11/27/wraping-c-code-with-python-ctypes-memory-and-pointers/

As pointed out in the tutorial I should free the memory after using the C function. Here is my C code

```
//C functions
double* getStuff(double *R_list, int items){

    double results[items];  
    double* results_p;   

    for(int i = 0; i < items; i++){ 
            res = calculation ; \\do some calculation
            results[i] = res;   }

        results_p = results;
        printf("C allocated address %p \n", results_p);

return results_p; }

void free_mem(double *a){
    printf("freeing address: %p\n", a);

    free(a);    }
```

Which I compile with `gcc -shared -Wl,-lgsl,-soname, simps -o libsimps.so -fPIC simps.c`

And python:

```
//Python
from ctypes import *
import numpy as np


mydll = CDLL("libsimps.so")
mydll.getStuff.restype = POINTER(c_double)
mydll.getStuff.argtypes = [POINTER(c_double),c_int]
mydll.free_mem.restype = None
mydll.free_mem.argtypes = [POINTER(c_double)]

R = np.logspace(np.log10(0.011),1, 100, dtype = float) #input


tracers = c_int(len(R))

R_c = R.ctypes.data_as(POINTER(c_double))


for_list = mydll.getStuff(R_c,tracers)
print 'Python allocated', hex(for_list)
for_list_py = np.array(np.fromiter(for_list, dtype=np.float64, count=len(R)))
mydll.free_mem(for_list)
```

Up to the last line the code does what I want it to and the `for_list_py` values are correct. However, when I try to free the memory, I get a Segmentation fault <s>and on closer inspection the address associated with `for_list` --> `hex(for_list)` is different to the one allocated to `results_p` within C part of the code.</s>

<s>As pointed out in this question, [Python ctypes: how to free memory? Getting invalid pointer error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13445568/python-ctypes-how-to-free-memory-getting-invalid-pointer-error)    , `for_list` will return the same address if `mydll.getStuff.restype` is set to `c_void_p`. But then I struggle to put the actual values I want into `for_list_py`. This is what I've tried:</s>

    <s>cast(for_list, POINTER(c_double) )
    for_list_py = np.array(np.fromiter(for_list, dtype=np.float64, count=len(R)))
    mydll.free_mem(for_list)</s>

<s>where the cast operation seems to change for_list into an integer.</s> I'm fairly new to C and very confused. Do I need to free that chunk of memory? If so, how do I do that whilst also keeping the output in a numpy array?  Thanks!

Edit: It appears that the address allocated in C and the one I'm trying to free are the same, though I still recieve a Segmentation fault.

```
C allocated address 0x7ffe559a3960
freeing address: 0x7ffe559a3960
Segmentation fault
```

If I do `print for_list` I get `<__main__.LP_c_double object at 0x7fe2fc93ab00>`

**Conclusion**

Just to let everyone know, I've struggled with c_types for a bit.

I've ended up opting for SWIG instead of c_types. I've found that the code runs faster on the whole (compared to the version presented here). I found this documentation on dealing with memory deallocation in SWIG very useful https://scipy-cookbook.readthedocs.io/items/SWIG_Memory_Deallocation.html  as well as the fact that SWIG gives you a very easy way of dealing with numpy n-dimensional arrays.

Comment: Is this a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13445568/python-ctypes-how-to-free-memory-getting-invalid-pointer-error and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54442674/freeing-memory-when-using-ctypes ?

Answer (score 3):

After `getStuff` function exits, the memory allocated to `results` array is not available any more, so when you try to free it, it crashes the program.

Try this instead:

```
double* getStuff(double *R_list, int items)
{
  double* results_p = malloc(sizeof((*results_p) * (items + 1));
  if (results_p == NULL)
  {
    // handle error
  }

  for(int i = 0; i < items; i++)
  { 
    res = calculation ; \\do some calculation
    results_p[i] = res;
  }

  printf("C allocated address %p \n", results_p);

  return results_p;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the response @Leo. What is `results_p[i] = NULL` meant to do? At this point `i` is not defined. Is this the last element? Then it is setting double to void*.

Comment: @Anna My bad, it was a mistake. I updated the answer.

Comment: I understand the memory is not available anymore, but this would be true also in an ordinary C run, without python wrapping and `ctypes`. Still, it is better to `free` memory before closing a C script. Why should it not be the case now?

Comment: What you should `free` is dynamically allocated memory (like in my anwser, using `malloc`), but you should not try to `free` memory allocated on the stack, like in code from @Anna 's question.

Comment: I see. But this does not solve the problem. I have a code structured like you proposed. The python script calls it 10^5 times and it allocates 10^8 `int` each time. I have noted the memory occupation grows and grows and the code eventually crashes. I think there must be a way to actually free the memory in a controlled manner.

Comment: My example only shows an implementation of the `getStuff` that will allow you to `free` the memory afterward, I did not suggest to not `free` the allocated memory.

Comment: It looks like. You did not explain how to: get the array's content in python and successively free the allocated block of memory.

Comment: You have an example of how to do that in the question itself, look at the function `free_mem`.

Comment: This answer has a solution to freeing memory when using ctypes: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13445568/python-ctypes-how-to-free-memory-getting-invalid-pointer-error