# How to free dynamically allocated string that are exported as a shared library from Python using ctypes

Tags: python, c++, c, ctypes

When exporting strings generated with `malloc` from C++ to python, using `ctypes` on the python end for loading the functions, how can you free those allocated strings?

For example.

```
#include <iostream>
#include "cstring"

extern "C" {
// this function uses dynamic memory allocation and returns a char*
char *a_func_that_generates_a_string() {
    std::string str = "AStringThatNeedsExportingToPythonViaASharedLib";
    char *cstr = (char *) malloc((str.size() + 1) * sizeof(char *)); // this now needs to be freed somewhere
    strcpy(cstr, str.c_str());
    return cstr;
}

// free a char*
void free_string(char *cstr) {
    free(cstr);
}
}
```

This can be compiled with the minimal CMake script:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.0)

add_library(HowToFreeCStringsFromPython SHARED ${HowToFreeCStringsFromPython_DIR}/source/HowToFreeCStringsFromPython.cpp)

install(TARGETS HowToFreeCStringsFromPython
        LIBRARY
        DESTINATION ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}
        )
```

And then used from python via:

```
import ctypes as ct
import os

_WORKING_DIRECTORY = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))
lib_path = os.path.join(_WORKING_DIRECTORY, 'libHowToFreeCStringsFromPython.so')

if not os.path.isfile(lib_path):
    raise ValueError

lib = ct.CDLL(lib_path)


def load_func(lib, funcname, argtypes, restype):
    func = lib.__getattr__(funcname)
    func.restype = restype
    func.argtypes = argtypes
    return func


a_func_that_generates_a_string = load_func(lib, "a_func_that_generates_a_string", [], ct.c_char_p)

free_str = load_func(lib, "free_string", [ct.c_char_p], ct.c_void_p)

astring_bytes = a_func_that_generates_a_string()
print(astring_bytes)
string = astring_bytes.decode()
free_str(astring_bytes)
print(string)
```

This outputs:

```
munmap_chunk(): invalid pointer
Aborted
```

What is the right strategy to do this?

Comment: What is the value that the allocating function returns, what is the value that the deallocating function receives?

Comment: You also should do a sanity test and not call any functions between the allocation and deallocation functions.  Just `allocate`, and immediately after that, `free_str`.

Comment: I found the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13445568/python-ctypes-how-to-free-memory-getting-invalid-pointer-error) if somebody with the rep points whats to mark as duplicate.

Comment: @CiaranWelsh I marked it; you should now have a button to accept it as a duplicate.