# LibXML2 failing to free memory when encapsulated in Python/ctypes

Tags: python, libxml2

My Python script is:

```
def xmlEncodeSpecialChars(doc: xmlDoc, input: str) -> str:
    '''
    Do a global encoding of a string, replacing the predefined entities this routine is reentrant, and result must be deallocated.

        doc:        the document containing the string
        input:      A string to convert to XML.
        Returns:    A newly allocated string with the substitution done.'''
        
    libXML = LibXML2() # DSO/DLL 

    libXML.xmlEncodeSpecialChars.restype = ctypes.c_char_p
    libXML.xmlEncodeSpecialChars.argtypes = ctypes.c_void_p, ctypes.c_char_p, 

    output: ctypes.c_char_p = libXML.xmlEncodeSpecialChars(doc, input.encode()); 
    Err = xmlGetLastError()
    if Err: raise LibErr(Err)
    ans = output.decode()
# free memory
    libXML.xmlMemFree.argtypes = ctypes.c_char_p, ;
    libXML.xmlMemFree(output)
    
    return ans
```

It properly returns an escaped string, but the xmlMemFree() generates a `Memory tag error` in Python though the equivalent C call to the same DLL works just fine.

How do I set up a `ctypes` memory free operation?

---edit---

The minimum reproducible (*Linux*) setup is:

```
def xmlEncodeSpecialChars(doc: xmlDoc, input: str) -> str:
    '''
    Do a global encoding of a string, replacing the predefined entities this routine is reentrant, and result must be deallocated.

        doc:        the document containing the string
        input:      A string to convert to XML.
        Returns:    A newly allocated string with the substitution done.'''
    
    libXML = ctypes.CDLL ("libxml2.so.2") # DSO/DLL 

    libXML.xmlEncodeSpecialChars.restype = ctypes.c_void_p
    libXML.xmlEncodeSpecialChars.argtypes = ctypes.c_void_p, ctypes.c_char_p, 

    output: ctypes.c_void_p = libXML.xmlEncodeSpecialChars(doc, input.encode()); 

    Err = xmlGetLastError() #   check for library error
    if Err: raise LibErr(Err)

    ans = ctypes.cast(output, ctypes.c_char_p).value.decode()                   #   convert to Python str

    libXML.xmlMemFree.argtypes = ctypes.c_void_p, ;libXML.xmlMemFree(output);   #   free memory, FIXME

    return ans

print(xmlEncodeSpecialChars(None, "<root>Some text with < and > characters</root>"))
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Python ctypes: how to free memory? Getting invalid pointer error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13445568/python-ctypes-how-to-free-memory-getting-invalid-pointer-error)

Comment: Your title says `c_void_p`, but the issue is with a `c_char_p`, and that is the root of the problem.  `c_char_p` is treated differently.  Why would you go to this trouble, anyway?  Python includes a thorough and well-integrated XML module that can do this directly.

Comment: @TimRoberts, I'd been using LibXML2 with all my C/C++ code, LabVIEW, Excel VBA and Python - I've got classes that work well and I understand inside and out - that's why.  And all these languages can share the same DOM, nodes, and XPath parser directly.

Comment: @jasonharper, I wish.  Logically, it seems it'd work, but doesn't.

Comment: Did you TRY changing the `c_char_p` to a `c_void_p`, as the link suggests?  Alternatively. since the `c_char_p` is converted to a normal Python string, you should be able to just remove the `xmlMemFree` call.  Python will clean up with the string goes out of scope.

Comment: Note: `ans = output.decode()` **can't** possibly work.

Comment: @TimRoberts Python doesn’t know if the returned char* is allocated from the heap or not and will not automatically free the memory. The Python string is a copy but the original memory is lost without the free.

Comment: @TimRoberts, Yes, I tried exactly that, trying c_void_p

Comment: I may have to do a deep dive and run the debugger on the DSO/DLL source.
@MarkTolonen when you say lost, you mean leaked and unrecoverable?  That's why I think this is so important, especially since I use this library so much.  The irony is I use xmlFree with the XPath results and documents without issue.

Comment: Yes it will leak. What “doesn’t work”?  The linked duplicate is the solution.

Comment: This appears to be a LibXML2 DSO/DLL issue, not Python and ctypes.  I'll see if I can change the keywords

Comment: Regarding your now-deleted question: The value it has is that it gets to stay on the site, along with the answer, for the future readers to see (that's the [point of the site](https://stackoverflow.com/tour), not just help the individual user). 1/2

Comment: 2/2 But if you make drastic changes to the question after getting an answer, that makes the answer useless and invalidates the work I put into it (see [1](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/143456/353058), [2](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/254521/2752075)), I now I'm either forced to delete the answer, or play a game of cat and mouse adapting it to every change of the question. Hence the downvote. I tried to explain under that question, but I guess I wasn't clear enough.

Comment: It didn't work with quotes even in 4.4.

Comment: Don't interpret downvotes as a personal attack, they're just an indication that the question needs to be fixed. See [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/333476/353058) (`# 4.4`) for example.

Answer (score 0):

In `ctypes`, `c_char_p` transforms a null-terminated C `char*` and returns a Python `bytes` object.  The pointer is lost.

Use `c_void_p` or `POINTER(c_char)` to maintain the pointer.  `string_at` can be used to read a null-terminated string at the returned address.

Untested:

```py
def xmlEncodeSpecialChars(doc: xmlDoc, input: str) -> str:
    '''
    Do a global encoding of a string, replacing the predefined entities this routine is reentrant, and result must be deallocated.

        doc:        the document containing the string
        input:      A string to convert to XML.
        Returns:    A newly allocated string with the substitution done.'''
    libXML = LibXML2() # DSO/DLL 

    libXML.xmlEncodeSpecialChars.restype = ctypes.c_void_p
    libXML.xmlEncodeSpecialChars.argtypes = ctypes.c_void_p, ctypes.c_char_p

    output: ctypes.c_void_p = libXML.xmlEncodeSpecialChars(doc, input.encode())
    Err = xmlGetLastError()
    if Err: raise LibErr(Err)
    ans = ctypes.string_at(output).decode()
# free memory
    libXML.xmlMemFree.argtypes = ctypes.c_void_p,
    libXML.xmlMemFree.restype = None
    libXML.xmlMemFree(output)
    return ans
```

Comment: I had tried this already and was convinced it would work. `Memory tag error occurs :0x55580b699828 
         bye
xmlMemFree(0x55580b699850) error
xmlMallocBreakpoint reached on block 0`

Comment: I'm happy to know about the `c_char_p`  conversion  and loss of pointer.  It still seems I'm losing the pointer 

Comment: @DannyHolstein You have some other issue if this doesn't work.  Make a [mcve] and provide a link to the DLL used.  I couldn't find any documentation link for `xmlEncodeSpecialChars`.  It can help to see how it is used in C code as well.  Does the returned string look correct when extracted with `string_at`?

Comment: I'm sure!  Just for giggles, I passed the pointer to `xmlStrlen()` and it worked perfectly!